# Create extendable enums for use in extendable interfaces

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-typings

**Context:** I am trying to develop a pattern for creating extendable state machines in typescript using the [TypeState](https://github.com/eonarheim/TypeState) library. TypeState provides a typesafe state machine for Typescript, and while not central to the problem I am having it helps illustrate my goal.

**Problem:** I am running into issues creating a scalable pattern for extending `enum` in Typescript and implementing them in `interface` and `class` declarations.

**Goal:** The psuedocode below illustrates what I would like my pattern to look like.

1) Define base `enum States`

2) Extend `enum States` with additional states resulting in `enum ExtendedStates`

2) Define `ParentInterface` using `States` and typed state machine

3) Extend `ParentInterface` via `ChildInterface` and override `States` with `ExtendedStates`

4) Implement `ParentInterface` in `class Parent`

5) Extend `class Parent` in `class Child` implementing `ChildInterface`

6) Be able to call `broadcastState()` from either class and get the current state.

I have used this pattern to great effect in other languages, and I would appreciate some help understanding the limitations of Typescript and any alternative patterns that can achieve the same goal.

```
import {TypeState} from "typestate";

enum States {
  InitialState
}

// extends is not available on enum, looking for alternative
enum ExtendedStates extends States {
  AdditionalState
}

/////////////////////////////////////////
// this works fine
interface ParentInterface {
  fsm: TypeState.FiniteStateMachine<States>;
  states: typeof States;
  message: string;
}

// incorrectly extends ParentInterface, types of fsm/states are incompatible
interface ChildInterface extends ParentInterface {
  fsm: TypeState.FiniteStateMachine<ExtendedStates>;
  states: typeof ExtendedStates;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////

class Parent implements ParentInterface {
  public fsm: TypeState.FiniteStateMachine<States>;
  public states: typeof States;
  public message: string = "The current state is: ";

  constructor(state: States | undefined) {
    state = state ? state : this.states.InitialState;
    this.fsm = new TypeState.FiniteStateMachine(state);
    this.broadcastCurrentState();
  }

  public broadcastCurrentState(): void {
    console.log(this.message + this.fsm.currentState);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent implements ChildInterface {
  public fsm: TypeState.FiniteStateMachine<ExtendedStates>;
  public states: typeof ExtendedStates;

  constructor(state: ExtendedStates | undefined) {
    state = state ? state : this.states.InitialState;
    this.fsm = new TypeState.FiniteStateMachine(ExtendedStates);
    this.broadcastCurrentState();
  }
}
```

Closest I've Gotten

```
import {TypeState} from "typestate";

enum States {
  InitialState
}

enum ExtendedStates {
  InitialState,
  ExtendedState
}

class Parent {
  public fsm: TypeState.FiniteStateMachine<States>;
  public states: typeof States;
  public message: string = "The current state is: ";

  // T is declared but never used
  constructor(state: <T> | undefined) {
    state = state ? state : this.states.InitialState;
    // cannot find name T
    this.fsm = new TypeState.FiniteStateMachine<T>(state);
    this.broadcastCurrentState();
  }

  public broadcastCurrentState(): void {
    console.log(this.message + this.fsm.currentState);
  }
}

// types of fsm are incompatible
class Child extends Parent {
  public fsm: TypeState.FiniteStateMachine<ExtendedStates>;
  public states: typeof ExtendedStates;

  constructor(state: ExtendedStates | undefined) {
    // Param not assignable to type <T>
    super(state);
  }
}
```

This attempt gets close to desired results, but does not compile and results in a lot of code duplication in the `enum`. It also loses the interfaces, which are not a requirement but do provide a nice safety net.

I'd love to hear what you all have to say. I feel like this is a powerful pattern and I am missing something simple in order to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason that it doesn't compile is because `Child` isn't a proper subtype of `Parent`.  The [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) says you should be able to use a `Child` object as a `Parent` object.  If I ask a `Parent` object for which state its state machine is in, and it tells me `ExtendedState`, then I've got a broken `Parent`, right?  So a `Child` is a broken `Parent`, which is bad, and is what TypeScript is warning you about.

Probably it's better to forget having a superclass/subclass relationship and just have a *generic* class:

```
class Generic<T extends States> {
  public fsm: TypeState.FiniteStateMachine<T>;
  public states: T;
  public message: string = "The current state is: ";

  // T[keyof T] means the values of T, in this case InitialState, etc    
  constructor(state: T[keyof T] | undefined) {
    state = state ? state : this.states.InitialState;
    // cannot find name T
    this.fsm = new TypeState.FiniteStateMachine<T>(state);
    this.broadcastCurrentState();
  }

  public broadcastCurrentState(): void {
    console.log(this.message + this.fsm.currentState);
  }
}
```

Now that *would* work if `States` were the right kind of object, but as you can noted, `enum`s aren't really that full-featured enough to be used in this way: you can't get anything to extend them.  So instead of using an `enum`, why not use an object which emulates it:

```
// make our own enum
type Enum<T extends string> = {[K in T]: K};

// create an enum from given values
function makeEnum<T extends string>(...vals: T[]): Enum<T> {
  const ret = {} as Enum<T>;
  vals.forEach(k => ret[k] = k)
  return ret;
}

// take an existing enum and extend it with more values
function extendEnum<T extends string, U extends string>(
  firstEnum: Enum<T>, ...vals: U[]): Enum<T | U> {
    return Object.assign(makeEnum(...vals), firstEnum) as any;  
}
```

In this case, an `Enum<>` is an object with specified string keys, whose values are the same as the key (this is a bit different from regular `enum`s whose values are numbers.  If you really want numbers that can probably be arranged but it would be more annoying to implement.  I've never used the `TypeState` library, so I don't know if it cares if the values are numbers or strings.) Now you can create your `States` and `ExtendedStates` like this:

```
const States = makeEnum('InitialState'); 
type States = typeof States; 
// States is { InitialState: 'InitialState' };

const ExtendedStates = extendEnum(States, 'ExtendedState');
type ExtendedStates = typeof ExtendedStates;
// ExtendedStates is { InitialState: 'InitialState', ExtendedState: 'ExtendedState' };
```

and create objects like this:

```
const parentThing = new Generic<States>(States.InitialState);
const childThing = new Generic<ExtendedStates>(ExtendedStates.InitialState);
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use x-extensible-enum. For clarification you can get help with: https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#112